# Modifying laravel table name in collection for output only

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models

```
class MerchOrder extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'merch_orders';

    protected $with = 'merchProducts';

    public function merchProducts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MerchProduct::class, 'merch_products_ordered', 'orderno', 'product')
            ->withPivot('quantity', 'price');
    }

}
```

and

```
class MerchProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'merch_products';

    public function merchOrders ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MerchOrder::class, 'merch_products_ordered', 'product', 'orderno');
    }

}
```

This is what is returned

```
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "receipt": "G4DD8C",
        "employee": 01,
        "location": 2,
        "time_insert": "2020-02-21 10:46:47",
        "time_update": "2020-02-23 06:11:23",
        "status": "delivered",
        "merch_products": [
            {
                "id": 45,
                "title": "Example Title",
                "desc": "Example Description",
                "price": "237.50",
                "pivot": {
                    "orderno": 57,
                    "product": 45,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "price": "237.50"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

how does one adjust the table name that is output in the related class? IE. this part, I want output as  "ordered" instead of the table name "merch_products"

```
"merch_products": [
            {
```

I've tried the laravel as() method but it just renames the "pivot" key, and everything else I can find only talks about renaming individual attributes but not the whole collection of attributes.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the relation as such if you want it to fetch by different name and pass the custom column name that you want to use as foreign reference. You can read more about [Laravel's Naming Convention](https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions) here.

You need to change MerchOrder model to the following:

```
class MerchOrder extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'merch_orders';

    protected $with = 'orders';

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MerchProduct::class, 'merch_products_ordered', 'orderno', 'product')
            ->withPivot('quantity', 'price');
    }

}
```